# how to match array field and nested array field in mongodb without using unwind

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

My json data will look like this

```
{
  "videoId": 29,
  "videoComments": [
    {
      "comment": "awsome",
      "userId": 15,
      "commentTime": "2022-03-01T12:37:49.734Z",
      "userName": "user1646127068323",
      "deletedbyowner": "FALSE",
      "_id": "621e139d8e4195079c86488",
      "replyComments": [
        {
          "replyComment": "thank you",
          "replyCommentTime": "2022-03-01T12:44:53.193Z",
          "replyDeletedbyowner": "FALSE",
          "_id": "621e154557fa7045e342540"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to match some conditions that I mentioned below :

1. match "videoId" == "29"
2. then match "videoComments.deletedbyowner" == "FALSE"
3. if I match second condition then I need to match
   "videoComments.replyComments.replyDeletedbyowner" == "FALSE"

I can't use unwind because my boss told me that unwind is a costly operation it will effect the app performance. so with out using unwind I need to match these conditions.
could you please help out of this.

Comment: you want to keep the documents that match your creteria unchained?  or you want to change the arrays also, to have only the members that much the creteria?

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XY8CVUn9k6y) what you are looking for? [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) could be used when querying arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- this keep the documents with `videoId=29`
- only the elements with `deletedbyowner="FALSE"`
- and only the elements with `replyDeletedbyowner="FALSE"`

*this is aggregate solution, we have also `$elemMatch` and `$` to project the matched element, but here you need match on nested arrays, so i think you need aggregation, but i am not completly sure.

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=71338221-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match":{"$expr":{"$eq":["$videoId", 29]}}},
 {"$set":
  {"videoComments":
   {"$map":
    {"input":"$videoComments",
     "in":
     {"$cond":
      [{"$ne":["$$this.deletedbyowner", "FALSE"]}, null,
       {"$mergeObjects":
        ["$$this",
         {"replyComments":
          {"$filter":
           {"input":"$$this.replyComments",
            "cond":{"$eq":["$$reply.replyDeletedbyowner", "FALSE"]},
            "as":"reply"}}}]}]}}}}},
 {"$set":
  {"videoComments":
   {"$filter":
    {"input":"$videoComments", "cond":{"$ne":["$$this", null]}}}}}])
```

Comment: this is perfectly working with my conditions thank you:)

Comment: @RoopeshKrishna ok good, if it works accept it as solution, this is for helping the one that answered, and for other people to know if answer worked and useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
collection_name.find(
  { videoId : 29 },
  { videoComments : { $elemMatch : { deletedbyowner : "FALSE", $elemMatch: { replyDeletedbyowner: "FALSE"} } }
).pretty();
```

I think this is what you are looking for. For more info check this [doc](https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/filter-elements-from-mongodb-arrays/)